# Design patterns for GUI for Java application with swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, awt

I am creating a simple application for my course in an university.
Now I am working on the GUI. As it is my first application using GUI I tried to implement the following layout:

I have a decicated class "MainWindow" which extends `JFrame`.
Therefore I created following classes which extend `JPanel` to use them as container.

To initialise these classes I am using a method which creates object variables for each class and then adds created objects to the window pane of the frame:

```
JPanel toolbar = new Toolbar();
JPanel statusbar = new Statusbar("Some status");
JPanel mainArea = new MainArea();
JPanel propertyArea = new PropertyArea();

this.getContentPane().add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.getContentPane().add(statusbar, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.getContentPane().add(mainArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.getContentPane().add(propertyArea, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

It works so far. But now I have a huge problem to access public methods which I defined in each of the `Panel` classes.

Here is an example:

In the class `Statusbar` I have a public method to set the background color to red

```
public void setWarning() {
    this.setBackground(Color.RED);
}
```

If I try to access this method by typing `statusbar.setWarning()` it fails.

Does anyone have an idea what I have to modify?

Comment: Yes, you should assign them to a variable with a type that contains the public method, not to a `JPanel` typed variable.

Comment: Thank you, it works now! :-)